# How to receive JSON object string in Node Express

Tags: json, node.js, express, polymer

I'm using Polymer `<iron-ajax>` to post `JSON.stringify` data to a Node Express server, but that JSON string converted to a weird format (seen below) that I cannot parse. I'd like to parse the `email` value.

`<iron-ajax>` body contents set with:

```
this.$.ajax.body = JSON.stringify({
  "email": "pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com",
  "full_name": "Pyae Phyoe Shein",
  "phone": "123456",
  "file":{},
  "question1_answer": "answer one",
  "question2_answer": "answer two",
  "question3_answer": "answer three",
  "question1": "What is question one?",
  "question2": "What is question two?",
  "question3": "What is question three?"
  })
```

Node Express receives:

```
{"{\"email\":\"pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com\",\"full_name\":\"Pyae Phyoe Shein\",\"phone\":\"123456\",\"file\":{},\"question1_answer\":\"answer one\",\"question2_answer\":\"answer two\",\"question3_answer\":\"answer three\",\"question1\":\"What is question one?\",\"question2\":\"What is question two?\",\"question3\":\"What is question three?\"}":""}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `JSON.stringify()` the contents of [`<iron-ajax>.body`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#property-body), as that would cause the body [to be sent as a string with its `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/6422490/iron-ajax.html#L391-L393) (instead of `application/json`), requiring conversion to JSON by your server.

Set `<iron-ajax>.body` to the intended `object` and `<iron-ajax>.contentType` to `application/json`, and the Express server should automatically deserialize it into a JSON object.

```
<iron-ajax url="http://httpbin.org/put"
           method="put"
           content-type="application/json"
           last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      response: {
        type: Object,
        observer: '_responseChanged'
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.$.ajax.body = {
        email: "pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com",
        full_name: "Pyae Phyoe Shein",
        phone: "123456",
        file: {},
        question1_answer: "answer one",
        question2_answer: "answer two",
        question3_answer: "answer three",
        question1: "What is question one?",
        question2: "What is question two?",
        question3: "What is question three?"
      };
      this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    },
    _responseChanged: function(response) {
      console.log('response', response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url="http://httpbin.org/put"
                 method="put"
                 id="ajax"
                 content-type="application/json"
                 last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MbmOem?editors=1011)

Comment: I've got that error from nodejs part `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/polymer/105724/apply. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.` even I've added `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it did JSON.stringify two times on the data object, so you shouldn't stringify the data object yourself.

Try,

```
this.$.ajax.body = {
  "email": "pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com",
  "full_name": "Pyae Phyoe Shein",
  "phone": "123456",
  "file":{},
  "question1_answer": "answer one",
  "question2_answer": "answer two",
  "question3_answer": "answer three",
  "question1": "What is question one?",
  "question2": "What is question two?",
  "question3": "What is question three?"
  };
```

You should get,

```
{"email":"pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com","full_name":"Pyae Phyoe Shein","phone":"123456","file":{},"question1_answer":"answer one","question2_answer":"answer two","question3_answer":"answer three","question1":"What is question one?","question2":"What is question two?","question3":"What is question three?"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to parse the JSON body of your POST request.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then in your express app.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

You can then access the body as a JSON object.

```
app.post('/whatever', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.email);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions: `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. `JSON.parse` converts a string into a JSON object while `JSON.stringify` converts a JSON object into a string.

What you are doing is **stringifying** something that is already a string, and hence the result.

Try this:

```
  blabla = JSON.parse('{"email": "pyaephyoeshein@gmail.com",   \
                        "full_name": "Pyae Phyoe Shein",       \
                        "phone": "123456",                     \
                        "file":{},                             \
                        "question1_answer": "answer one",      \
                        "question2_answer": "answer two",      \
                        "question3_answer": "answer three",    \
                        "question1": "What is question one?",  \
                        "question2": "What is question two?",  \
                        "question3": "What is question three?" \
                        }') ;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(blabla,4)) ;
```

Notes:

(1) The `4` tells the method to indent every level in the hierarchy of the JSON by 4 spaces when converting it into a string.

(2) The `\` is needed to split define a string in more than one line.

Hope this makes things clearer for you.